# Is LINQ to SQL the best way to build a Model or create my own classes

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, model

I am develop a medium system in ASP.net with MS SQL Server Database and I wonder **what is the best way to create a model layer with LINQ or create own classes that dealing with database?**

Comment: Hi, please consider marking an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is subjective, but I think the easiest is to use [LINQ to SQL.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Using the LINQ designer is a great way to build your model in a UI avoiding the need to write any code.  You can setup object hierarchy using the inheritance option and also have associated classes which you can access via the datacontext in code.  All of the SQL is then handled for you and means you don't have to write anything, simply call SubmitChanges() on the datacontext.  All of the generated code can be viewed, but there is a lot to take in.

I would suggest to try writing your own classes manually with the LINQ attributes etc so you get an idea of what it is doing behind the scenes.  Then you will realise how the inheritance and association is implemented and actually makes the designer easier to understand too.